# English terminology for something that scales with n!

Tags: terminology, factorial

This is not a real math question, but a math terminology question.

If something scales as $\exp(n)$, one can say it increases exponentially in $n$.

What do you call it, when it increases as $n!$? Is the term "factorially"?  I've never heard the term before but then again I'm not a native speaker.

Comment: "Super-exponential" includes everything that is faster than exponential, which includes factorial. I've not heard a word specifically for factorial speed.

Comment: Indeed, super-exponential is right.